# How can I execute a statement and ignore warnings with tryCatch?

Tags: r, try-catch

I tried the following code:

```
x <- NULL
tryCatch(
  x <- sqrt(-1),
  warning = function(cond) print(paste("Ignore: ", conditionMessage(cond)))
)
# [1] "Ignore:  NaNs produced"
```

Expected output:

```
# [1] "Ignore:  NaNs produced"
x
#NaN
```

Notice that x is still NULL. No value has been assigned.

- I tried `x <<-`, but that doesn't work.
- I would like to show the ignored warning, instead of just suppressing the warnings. After `suppressWarnings(x <- sqrt(-1))` I do not know how to recover the warning message.

Comment: Why not just `suppressWarnings(x <- sqrt(-1))`?

Comment: in your code `x` is created in `tryCatch` first parameter which is a fenced expression. You can instead use `x <<- sqrt(-1)` which evades the fence or more simply `x <- tryCatch(sqrt(-1), ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `tryCatch(.., warning=)`, the first time the warning happens, the expression is interrupted and control is never returned to it. In order to "ignore" warnings, you need `withCallingHandlers` and `invokeRestart("mufflewarning")`.

```r
withCallingHandlers(
  x <- sqrt(-1),
  warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
x
# [1] NaN
```

One good reference for studying error/warning conditions is https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html.

I think there are two times when it makes sense to me to use `"muffleWarning"` instead of `suppressWarnings`:

- when I want to suppress *specific warnings only*, and allow all others to emit; this is by far the majority use-case for me; and
- when you want to change something because of a warning; I don't have a clear example of what to use this, as it is 100% contextual.